# angular 2 - how to keep array's value synced with input's value

Tags: angular

I have a var `this.optionCollection =[]`

And I have multiple dynamic inputs (see my code). I want when I type something in the inputs, it's value will be saved back to the array. Here is my try

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'SomeOptions',
        template: `
            <form (submit)="onSubmit()">
                <div *ngFor="let i of optionCollection; let index = index">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Add a Choice" [(ngModel)]="optionCollection[index]" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" />
                    <b class="delete" (click)= "removeClick(index)">-</b>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        `,

    })
    export class OptionComponent {
        optionCollection : string[]
        constructor() {
            this.optionCollection = ['','']
        }
        addClick(event:any) {
            event.preventDefault()
            this.optionCollection.push('')
        }
        removeClick(index){
            this.optionCollection.splice(index,1)
        }
        onSubmit() {
            console.log('submit')
        }
    }
```

Problem: input's value not properly saved to the array and there is weird behaviors as I'm typing, you can check out that behavior in this video below

http://youtu.be/V-WpaxZFVG8

Comment: can you share your plnkr. why you have used this.optionCollection = [' ',' ']?

Comment: because I want to have 2 inputs by default. There could be better way to load dynamic element into a container, but the array ['',''] is what I thought of when trying to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have list of primitives so on every typing in any input ngFor directive will redraw your list.

Possible solutions:

1) using trackBy

```
*ngFor="let i of optionCollection; let index = index; trackBy: trackByFn"

trackByFn(index) {
  return index;
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tKPFBACiVfa8ErgGBlxR?p=preview)**

2) using object instead of string

```
<div *ngFor="let item of optionCollection; let idx = index">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Add a Choice" [(ngModel)]="item.text" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" />
  <b class="delete" (click)= "removeClick(idx)">-</b>
</div>

constructor() {
  this.optionCollection = [{ text: '' }, { text: '' }];
}
addClick(event: any) {
  event.preventDefault()
  this.optionCollection.push({ text: '' })
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/zuZq7WjWWt9y0geOMlga?p=preview)**

Answer (score -1):

As string is a primitive data type. By having array of empty string means you are referencing same location.

Try this,
1) Create a class

```
export class MyObj {
    value: string;
}
```

2) Your array should look like

```
optionCollection : MyObj[]
    constructor() {
        let obj1 = new MyObj();
        let obj2 = new MyObj();
        let obj3 = new MyObj();
        this.optionCollection = [obj1,obj2,obj3]
    }
```

3) In your template, use

```
[(ngModel)]="i.value"
```

Hope this help!